# Django - Dynamic Tables - Add rows and columns

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to dynamically add columns to my DB.

For example. When the user clicks "Add Column" in the UI, Django adds a column in the database.

Are there tutorials on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: can you explain about your use case more?

Comment: @MahdiSorkhmiri He wants to add a column dynamically in the UI and saved the column in the DB.

Comment: i can get those information from the question it self i want to get more familiar with the use case @MohammadReza

Answer (score 2):

For doing this, it's more efficient to use NoSql databases.
Also if you want to use RDBMS, you can use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) or use below model:

```py
class Column(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    # more options

class Value(models.Model):
    column = models.ForeignKey(Column, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    # more options
```

Comment: Hey thanks - I will research into this. I assume I can use Postgres for everything else and use JSONFields for my use case. I mostly watch youtube videos to learn - any suggestions that will get me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you should learn how to query JSONFields and learn how it work.